# How much longer does a Warder live?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

It is said in several of the books that a Warder has increased strength and skill, resistance to hunger and thirst, and increased lifespan, but it never says how much longer. Obviously not as old as an AES Sedai, but longer than a man that can't channel. Does anybody know how much longer Warders live?

Answer (score 7):

### No longer than a normal man.

Robert Jordan answered this in [an interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=144) (item 6 on the linked page):

> **Do Warders have a regular lifespan?**
>
> ROBERT JORDAN: Yes they do. They hang on to what you would call 'vitality' longer than the average man, but they live a normal lifespan. They do get things out of the bond, but not a longer life.

Answer (score 0):

He literally says they hang on to vitality longer than the average man so it probably wouldn't be that extraordinary for a warder to live to be like 110ish I mean people have done that now people live to be over a hundred all the time now my friend's grandma is 104 science is saying that the human lifespan is 120 so maybe if one took care of themselves really well they could even live that long I kind of doubt it but I still think that 100 to 110 wouldn't be that crazy

Comment: As shown in [Rand al'Thor answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/150722/122024), the author of the series, Robert Jordan, has acknowledged the vitality quote, but very clearly stated that Warders in fact have a normal lifespan.